# Is it possible to use 2 different font for same element, 1 for English & another for Tamil(unicode)

Tags: javascript, css, unicode, fonts, google-fonts

I want to use "Arial Unicode MS" for tamil text and I want to use "Open Sans" for English.
But both are in same line, not a separate element.

> *ORGANIC Marachekku Gingelly Oil 500 ml (மரச்செக்கு நல்லெண்ணெய்)*

Now on this line, English language should be "open sans" and Tamil (foreign) language should be "Arial Unicode MS"

How do I achieve that in CSS? Should I need to use JS? is so How?

Comment: do you'd add a `<span>` with style that includes a `font-family`

Comment: It is impossible with a single element. But you can achieve this with multiple inline elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.

Do you think `that emoji`  is really part of the Consolas or Menlo font families that are being used to render that <code> element's text? It's not.

What happens here is that the browser will go all the road through the defined font-families, until it finds one which declared it is able to handle that glyph. If it can't, then it will search all the list of OS defined fonts.

So in the StackOverflow case of the <code> element we have

```
Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,sans-serif
```

On my system (macOs) none of these can represent the glyph "", so it falls back to a system font (Apple Color Emoji). Which means the <code> element indeed has two different fonts being used for its only textNode: Menlo for `that emoji`  part and the system font for "".

---

---

In your case, since "Open Sans" font only supports standard ISO Latin 1, Latin CE, Greek and Cyrillic character sets, you can simply do

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial Unicode MS", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span>ORGANIC Marachekku Gingelly Oil 500 ml (மரச்செக்கு நல்லெண்ணெய்)</span>
```

and the Tamil part will happily fallback to *Arial Unicode MS* where available. (*Btw, you may want to declare an other fallback font for systems that don't have it installed*).

---

Now, there may also be cases where one wants to use a font that does support a lot of character sets but for only a few glyphs.
For such cases, you can use the [unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range) property of the `@font-face` declaration.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'sans-serif-vowels';
  src: local('Arial'), local("Helvetica Neue"), local("Helvetica");
  unicode-range: U+61, U+65, U+69, U+6f, U+75, U+41, U+45, U+49, U+4f, U+55;
}

body{
  font-family: sans-serif-vowels, cursive;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In accumsan ante a consectetur volutpat. Donec venenatis tristique gravida. Morbi ultricies congue justo, sed condimentum neque elementum sit amet. Duis in nisl ultricies turpis gravida vestibulum. Aliquam commodo velit in neque convallis posuere quis hendrerit libero. Nullam tempor, mauris at posuere convallis, leo ante pharetra erat, eget accumsan quam sem eu erat.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation it works. But not on Android Chrome. But I am not worried about it now.